# Emacs doesn't open a new frame

Tags: start-up, linux

Emacs does not start in a new frame.

If I'm in a terminal running Bash and enter `$>emacs` the editor is opened inside this terminal, and produces exactly the same behavior as `$>emacs -nw`. I have what I think is an OK `DISPLAY` variable, `:0`.  If I try to start it using `gmrun` outside of a terminal, nothing happens.

I'm using Xmonad as a window manager.  I noticed something weird:  if I invoke `$> gmrun` from the command line in a window, I get the small window to type in the command. Entering `emacs` and hitting enter causes emacs to open inside the terminal in which the `gmrun` command was executed.

What configuration items would force emacs to start without creating a new frame?

Comment: You don't by chance have a non-X version of Emacs installed?  On Ubuntu, for instance, this would be the emacs-nox package.

Answer (score 1):

Many linux distributions have an `emacs-nox` package or similar, including CentOS and Ubuntu.  Make sure that the GUI version is installed; the package is called just `emacs` on CentOS.

Note that `xemacs` is a different (but related) text editor.

Answer (score 1):

For a generic distribution to figure out whether you have a GUI version of Emacs run:

```
ldd `which emacs` | grep -i gtk
```

If that returns something you have the gtk (GUI) version of Emacs.

- There is a Motiff GUI version also out there. I guess you can check for that with replacing gtk with motiff in that command.

Comment: Maybe a better way to find out your build options is to do M-x report-emacs-bug, give "Test" as the subject and scroll down to find the build options. Mine are:  "XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG IMAGEMAGICK SOUND GPM DBUS GSETTINGS NOTIFY
ACL LIBSELINUX GNUTLS LIBXML2 FREETYPE M17N_FLT LIBOTF XFT ZLIB
TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS GTK3 X11".
GTK3 and X11 are the keys here. And don't send that bug report email by accident :)